# Change base url dynamically from spinner

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I've got spinner in my login activity with url list. I would like to change base url dynamically, based on selected url. How can i do it? Below is my Retrofit client:

```
public class RetrofitClient {

private static Retrofit retrofit;

private static final String BASE_URL="Dynamically_URL";


public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance(){

    if(retrofit==null){

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .connectTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        retrofit= new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First save your selected spinner item to Shared Preferences

```
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {           
               @Override
               public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Cons.PRIVATE_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("url_selected", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()).apply();
}
           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){}

});
```

Then call saved url on shared Preferences on your retrofit Client

```
public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance(Context context) {

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Cons.PRIVATE_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  baseurl = sharedPreferences.getString("url_selected", "");  

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .connectTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        retrofit= new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseurl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can i call SharedPrefrences from retrofit client? When i try to use it in getRetrofitInstance(), i 've got : Cannot resolve getSharedPreferences

Comment: Updated anwser @OLIKER , you can set param context from the function param